# How to get the response from webservice

Tags: qt

Without using QSoap, how can I call a webservice using Http and store the response in a string? If possible, please provide code.

Answer (score 1):

Check [QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qnetworkaccessmanager.html).

Should help you accomplish what it seems you want to do.

If that's not what you want, being more specific about your issue helps. :-)